# Display a field depending on a checkbox

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I have a form with a checkbox field and I want basically when this checkbox is checked, display a field below.

I do not know what is the best practice in symfony to do that...

Form builder :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
        ->add('protected', 'checkbox', array(
            'label' => 'Protected by a password ?',
            'required' => false,
            'mapped' => false
        ))
        ->add('password', 'password', array(
            'label' => 'Mot de passe',
            'required' => false
        ))
}
```

So if the field 'protected' is checked, I want to display 'password' field.

Comment: why dont you do this jQuery?

Comment: I wonder if there is not another way using a Symfony process

Comment: You can use the symfony form events such as the `The FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA Event` (cf: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#b-the-formevents-post-set-data-event) but you'll still have to refresh your form (with ajax or by reloading the page)

Comment: I don't want to refresh the page, I want to do this dynamically @Coussinsky

Comment: Then you have to attach an js event on your checkbox and call your form with ajax to reload it without reloading the page (or use nodejs)

Comment: Ok, but you agree that this is a lot of processing to only display a field based on a checkbox...

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with jquery.

Hide the field with css ( i would suggest to do this with a class instead)

```
->add('password', 'password', array(
    'label' => 'Mot de passe',
    'required' => false,
    'attr' => array('style' => 'display:none;')
))
```

and then in jquery:

```
$('#checkbox_id').click(function() {
     $('.password_id')[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();
});
```

I hope this helped!

Comment: thanks for the answer, I finally decide to do this using jquery too